# SwiftUI core data optional and non-optional properties

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I am having trouble with a core data entity and SwiftUI. In my view, some properties are non-optional when they should be and I do not understand why.

Here is my **Entry** core data entity:

[image: Entry core data entity]

Here is how I am attempting to use this in a view:

```swift
if entry.text != nil {
    Text(entry.text!)
}

if entry.number != nil {
    Text("\(entry.number, specifier: "%.0f")")
}

if entry.boolean != nil {
    Text(entry.boolean ? "True" : "False")
}
```

My issue is that for `entry.number` and `entry.boolean`, swift complains of `Comparing non-optional value of type 'Double' to 'nil' always returns true`.

This does not happen for `entry.text`. I have checked the values by running `print(entry)` and `number` and `boolean` are `nil` in the persistent store.

I understand that core data optionals and swift optionals are different. However, shouldn't all **Entry** properties be optional in this case? Why is SwiftUI complaining that they are not?

Comment: You should really use `if let` to unwrap your optionals if you plan on using them like that.

Comment: @Andrew that's a great tip, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your entity the default setting for Boolean and Double is to  use scalar (primitive) types and they are non-optional because Objective-C (which is what Core Data is based on) can't handle optional scalar types.

This is how they are defined in code

```
@NSManaged public var boolean: Bool
@NSManaged public var number: Double
```

If you uncheck to use scalar type (Inspector Cmd-alt-0) then the underlying type would be NSNumber instead and they would be optional

```
@NSManaged public var number: NSNumber?
@NSManaged public var boolean: NSNumber?
```